# To store and retrieve schedule from database the exact same location

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, schedule

I'm trying to create a class schedule here.
I know I'm not supposed to ask before trying anything, the problem is I can't think of any logic to do this.
As you can see I have a table as below [image]

What I want to do is, I want to store the data in the database, and when I retrieve the data, I want to display it in the exact same location as the picture. Please help me out.

EDIT : I'm a beginner in programming please go easy on me

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: _"I know I'm not supposed to ask before trying anything"_ -- then why did you?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I'm asking because I'm stuck, been at it for 1 month. All I can think of is how to store it but I couldn't find a way to retrieve it the exact same way.

Comment: As I see your example you can use just mysql cross table! search on Google! But this only work one hour intervals!

Answer (score 0):

1. Code the PHP to create the HTML to display the schedule as it is in the image above, but without the courses.  Hint: you should use a two dimensional array of days and times.
2. Create a two dimensional array of the schedule, using array keys that match those you created in step 1.
3. Write the code to put the schedule from step 2 in the display from step 1.
4. Create your database and a table for the schedule.
5. Write the code that reads the schedule from the database, discard the code that put the schedule into the display from the array.

Comment: Thanks sir, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

1. store data like this:
   [image]
2. this is the query.

   ```
   $query = "SELECT time_format(schedule,'%T') as schedule,
           if(dayname(schedule)='Sunday',subject,'') as Sunday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Monday',subject,'') as Monday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Tuesday',subject,'') as Tuesday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Wednesday',subject,'') as Wednesday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Thursday',subject,'') as Thursday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Friday',subject,'') as Friday, 
           if(dayname(schedule)='Saturday',subject,'') as Saturday 
       FROM scheduleTable
       WHERE schedule between '2016-7-25' and '2016-7-31 23:59'";
   ```

3.this is the result from the query

[image]

Then you can use PHP to style the table or send it to Ajax let javascript do the job.